# Return farthestK from val: Can't import anything other than java.util.Arrays

Tags: java

Need to return the k elements a[i] such that ABS(a[i] - val) are the k largest evaluation. My code only works for integers greater than val. It will fail if integers less than val. Can I do this without importing anything other than java.util.Arrays? Any help will be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Selector {

private Selector() {
 } 
public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {// This line should not change                  
  int[] b = new int[a.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
     b[i] = Math.abs(a[i] - val);
  }
  Arrays.sort(b);
  int[] c = new int[k];
  int w = 0;
  for (int i = b.length-1; i > b.length-k-1; i--) {       
     c[w] = b[i] + val;
     w++;     
  }
  return c;    
}
```

test case:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SelectorTest {


 /** Fixture initialization (common initialization
  *  for all tests). **/
 @Before public void setUp() {
 }
  @Test public void farthestKTest() {
       int[] a = {-2, 4, -6, 7, 8, 13, 15};
       int[] expected = {15, -6, 13, -2};
       int[] actual = Selector.farthestK(a, 4, 4);
       Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
     }
 }

 There was 1 failure:
 1) farthestKTest(SelectorTest)
 arrays first differed at element [1]; expected:<-6> but was:<13>
 FAILURES!!!
 Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: Well, since you can only use Arrays, maybe you could use a DSU pattern (decorate-sort-undecorate).  I'm not too familiar with doing so in Java, but I'd imagine you'd have to implement a custom comparator too.  Might just be too much work.

Answer (score 1):

By storing the distance as an absolute value, you destroy your last for loop which recalculates the original value from the abs-value.

How about using a comparator who is using the abs value for comparison, but storing the difference of the array value from the search value in your array b?

This would be something like this here:

```
public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {// This line should not change
    Integer[] b = new Integer[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      b[i] = a[i] - val;
    }
    Arrays.sort(b, new Comparator<Integer>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        return Integer.valueOf(Math.abs(arg0)).compareTo(Math.abs(arg1));
      }
    });
    int[] c = new int[k];
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = b.length - 1; i > b.length - k - 1; i--) {
      c[w] = b[i] + val;
      w++;
    }
    return c;
  }
```

Comment: When I test the test case above, it reports: SelectorTest.java:48: error: method farthestK in class Selector cannot be applied to given types;
             int[] actual = Selector.farthestK(a, 4, 4);
                                    ^
  required: Integer[],int,int
  found: int[],int,int
  reason: actual argument int[] cannot be converted to Integer[] by method invocation conversion
1 error

Comment: You did not provide code for your SelectorTest class. I tested with the method you provided. However your method signature of farthestK indicates you are passing in an Integer[] while the code sample I wrote expects a int[]. I am just using Integer[] internally because this makes using a Comparator for sorting easier.

Comment: I updated my SelectorTest.java code. Please check it! Thanks!

Comment: This code runs for me, just copied code from above and test case from you. Works like a charm. Try to rebuild the classes / refresh you IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> ABS(a[i] - val)

This is your sorting criterion, so you need to implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that applys it to the two values to be compared an return the result of the comparison of the two resulting values.

```
public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {
    // copy into an array of non primitive integers 
    // for using in the sort method
    Integer[] b = new Integer[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }

    final int v = val; // make val final for access in anonymous class
    Arrays.sort(b, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            int v1 = Math.abs(o1.intValue() - v);
            int v2 = Math.abs(o2.intValue() - v);
            return - (v1 - v2); // return inverted result of comparison
                                // for convenient copying later
                                // or just (v2 - v1)
        }
    });

    // copy first k elements
    int[] c = new int[k];
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c[i] = b[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Note that the code above also imports `java.util.Comparator` . If you are not allowed to impot it then the method [Arrays.sort(T[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) will not fit your needs since you dont want to sort the numbers in their numerical order. In that case you'll have to implement your own sorintg algorithm and use the same comparison logic as above.

Here is an implementation using a simple [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for int arrays:

```
public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(sort(a, val), k);
}

private static int compare(int o1, int o2, int v) {
    int v1 = Math.abs(o1 - v);
    int v2 = Math.abs(o2 - v);
    return (v2 - v1);
}

private static int[] sort(int[] a, int v) {
    return mergesort(a, v);
}

private static int[] mergesort(int[] a, int v) {
    if(a.length <= 1) {
        return a;
    }
    int m = a.length / 2;
    int[] la = mergesort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, m), v);
    int[] ra = mergesort(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, m, a.length), v);
    return merge(la, ra, v);
}

private static int[] merge(int[] la, int[] ra, int v) {
    int[] a = new int[la.length + ra.length];
    int il = 0, ir = 0, ia = 0;
    while(il < la.length && ir < ra.length) {
        if(compare(la[il], ra[ir], v) <= 0) {
            a[ia++] = la[il++];
        } else {
            a[ia++] = ra[ir++];
        }
    }
    while(il < la.length) {
        a[ia++] = la[il++];
    }
    while(ir < ra.length) {
        a[ia++] = ra[ir++];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Basically you can even do all the copying by yourself and even get rid of the import for [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Also note that you actually do not need all the copying at all of the left and right arrays for the mersort. All you need is a single new array of the same length of the original one and work with start/end indices to idendify left and right arrays.